# Reload ListView from Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a listview on my app managed with an Adapter. Inside the adapter, i have a button to delete an item from the list, my problem is, i cant see the changes right away, i have to reset the activity in order to refresh the list. Is there any way to refresh the data from the getView on the adapter?

Activity

public class gestionCategorias extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ListView listaCategorias;
private SQLAdmin sql;
private ArrayList<CategoriasModel> arrayCat;
private ImageButton delete;
private CategoriaAdapter adapter;
private EditText agregarCategoriaInput;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gestion_categorias);

    listaCategorias = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaCategorias);
    arrayCat = new ArrayList<>();

    sql = new SQLAdmin(this);
    delete = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.eliminarCategoria);
    agregarCategoriaInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agregarCategoriaInput);

    loadDataInListView();


}


public void loadDataInListView() {
    arrayCat = sql.getAllCategorias();
    adapter = new CategoriaAdapter(this, arrayCat);
    listaCategorias.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Adapter => (The idea is to refresh the list when i click on the "eliminar" button)

```
public class CategoriaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<CategoriasModel>arrayList;

public CategoriaAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<CategoriasModel>arrayList){
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.categorialv , null);

        final SQLAdmin sql = new SQLAdmin(context.getApplicationContext());

        final TextView categoria_nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombreCategoria);

        final CategoriasModel categoriasModel = arrayList.get(position);

        categoria_nombre.setText(categoriasModel.getNombre());

        ImageButton eliminar = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eliminarCategoria);

        eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                                sql.eliminarCategoria(arrayList.get(position).getId());
                                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext() , "Categoria eliminada" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need to add ```notifyDataSetChanged()``` inside ``` eliminar.setOnClickListener```

Comment: @HussainAbbas it doesnt do anything

Comment: your adapter class is wrong you need to bind this view with your list view

Comment: maybe you can try to add a delete listener inside your adapter, and once the user clicks the ImageButton, it will use the listener to notify your activity. Then you can delete the item in your activity and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by adding the following code to my adapter =>

```
 if (context instanceof gestionCategorias){
                    ((gestionCategorias)context).loadDataInListView();
                }
```

LoadDataInListView loads all the data again and updates the listview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call "notifyDataSetChanged()" after deleting the item.

```
eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                            sql.eliminarCategoria(arrayList.get(position).getId());
                            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext() , 
                                "Categoria eliminada" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            notifyDataSetChanged(); // refresh the list
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try this, clear the list and adding the new one

```
public void loadDataInListView() {
        arrayCat.clear();
        arrayCat = sql.getAllCategorias();
        adapter = new CategoriaAdapter(this, arrayCat);
        listaCategorias.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```